# Combine background CSS rules into 1 line

Tags: css

How can I combine the following CSS rules into 1 line?  Is this even possible?

```
background-color: #2773bb;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
background-size: 16px 16px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('/Content/img/icons/search.svg');
```

I've been playing with different combinations, but neither seems to work.  For example, the following does not produce the desired result.

```
background: url('/Content/img/icons/search.svg') center center 16px 16px no-repeat #2773bb;
```

Maybe there is some kind of tool online, where I can paste a bunch of background properties and it will consolidate them for me?

Comment: Almost there, just need to add a `/` between the position and size, so `...center / 16px...`

Comment: And the reason it got down voted is???

Comment: Downvoting is anonymous, so we can only guess as to why this was downvoted. My guess is that the phrasing of the question was a clear request for free work (I've edited that out). If you can write your questions in the genuine expectation that you will do the bulk of it (i.e. the implementation of an answer) then that will usually be received in a better fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order will be

- background-image
- background-position
- background-size
- background-repeat
- background-color

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.main {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) center center/16px 16px no-repeat #2773bb;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

> [**Reference Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way possible is this since background-size isn't a parameter in background.

```
background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
background-size: 16px 16px
```

Although in case you have such specific rules, is okay to have them splitted for better readability and the performance impact will be near-inexistent